# Sum of a particular field by matching particular field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

we are using mongoose

We have this collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5596c195336cbb042728c83b"),
    "cameraId" : ObjectId("559514d3f20fb7e959a5b078"),
    "orignalFilePath" : "/opt/safecamz/recording/55950adaa24f46d255acfe90/559514d3f20fb7e959a5b078/1A01270PAA0012/2000-01-09/001/dav/23/23.26.09-23.27.33[M][0@0][0].dav",
    "recordingDuration" : 11.042,
    "recordingLocation" : "/opt/safecamz/recording/55950adaa24f46d255acfe90/559514d3f20fb7e959a5b078/video/23.26.09-23.27.33[M][0@0][0].mp4",
    "userId" : ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90"),
    "created" : ISODate("2015-07-03T17:08:37.537Z"),
    "recordingSize" : "1259.3857421875",
    "recordingWowzaUrl" : "55950adaa24f46d255acfe90/559514d3f20fb7e959a5b078/video/23.26.09-23.27.33[M][0@0][0].mp4",
    "recordingName" : "23.26.09-23.27.33[M][0@0][0].mp4",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now we want to add **recordingSize** by **userId** 
for example if there are 10,000 recording then sum of recordingSize where userId=ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90")

we try to use `$sum` but we are unable to get correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation. Let's assume sample data derived from your sample:

```
> db.recordings.find({}, {_id: 0, userId: 1, recordingSize: 1, recordingDuration:1})
{ "recordingDuration" : 11.042, "userId" : ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90"), "recordingSize" : "1259.3857421875" }
{ "recordingDuration" : 11.042, "userId" : ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90"), "recordingSize" : "3000.3857421875" }
```

Let's try `recordingDuration` first and see the sum in `totalDuration`:

```
> db.recordings.aggregate([{$project: {userId:1, recordingDuration:1}}, {$group: { _id: '$userId', totalDuration: { $sum: '$recordingDuration' }}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90"), "totalDuration" : 22.084 }
```

The problem is that `recordingSize` is a String, that's why `$sum` will not work:

```
> db.recordings.aggregate([{$project: {userId:1, recordingSize:1}}, {$group: { _id: '$userId', totalSize: { $sum: '$recordingSize' }}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90"), "totalSize" : 0 }
```

More details here: [$sum (aggregation)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Comment: Opps you are correct , now I change it to Number can you please make query in which first it matches userId and then return the Sum of recordingSize , In your query it finds for all but I want only for a particular User

Comment: Then you just need to add a `$match` like this: `db.recordings.aggregate([{$match: {userId: ObjectId("55950adaa24f46d255acfe90")}}, {$project: {userId:1, recordingDuration:1}}, {$group: { _id: '$userId', totalDuration: { $sum: '$recordingDuration' }}}])`. More details: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: I find the solution we use this Query 
db.recordings.aggregate([{$match: {userId:ObjectId("55924170480ba7ec307f6a76")}}, {$group: { _id: '$userId', totalSize: { $sum: '$recordingSize' }}}])
and Thanks for your help